# Dask, create a dataframe from several dask arrays

Tags: python, dask

Suppose I have a set of dask arrays such as:

```
c1 = da.from_array(np.arange(100000, 190000), chunks=1000)
c2 = da.from_array(np.arange(200000, 290000), chunks=1000)
c3 = da.from_array(np.arange(300000, 390000), chunks=1000)
```

is it possible to create a dask dataframe from them?  In pandas i could say:

```
data = {}
data['c1'] = c1
data['c2'] = c2
data['c3'] = c3

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

is there a similar way to do this with dask?

Comment: I suspect that you could do this with a combination of `dd.from_dask_array` and `dd.concat(..., axis=1)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np 
import dask.array as da, dask.dataframe as dd

c1 = da.from_array(np.arange(100000, 190000), chunks=1000)
c2 = da.from_array(np.arange(200000, 290000), chunks=1000)
c3 = da.from_array(np.arange(300000, 390000), chunks=1000)

# generate dask dataframe
ddf = dd.concat([dd.from_dask_array(c) for c in [c1,c2,c3]], axis = 1) 
# name columns
ddf.columns = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```